# CSS images doesn't float to left

Tags: css

I creating a buddypress theme but when I need to display online user, my css won't float my image to the left. I have set the images size, padding and margin, and it working it just unable to float my image

This is the HTML code

```
    <div class="item-title-members"> <a href="http://demo.com/user1">ovolo</a>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="item-avatar"> <a href="http://demo.com/user2" title="admin"><img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img89/3994/e6n6.png" class="avatar user-1-avatar avatar- photo" width="150" height="150" alt="Profile picture of admin" /></a>

    <div class="item-title-members"> <a href="http://demo.com/user2">admin</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
div.avatar-block {
height: 200px;
width: 94%;
}

div.avatar-block .item-avatar {
position: absolute;
float: left;
}

div.item-avatar a {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}

.item-title-members {
text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j9zru/1/

Comment: You shouldn't use `position` and `float` together.

Comment: you may also use .item-avatar img{display:block; float:left;} :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:absolute` from .item-avatar class

```
div.avatar-block .item-avatar {
 float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change div on `avatar-block` to position relative:

```
div.avatar-block .item-avatar {
    position: relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified on `.item-avatar` both `position: absolute` and `float: left`.  Absolute positioning will override any other positioning directives and `absolute` without explicit offsets will position the content at `left: 0px; top: 0px` within the nearest parent with `position` other than `static` (or no position at all, as `static` is the default).

Therefore, in your case, the best thing is to simply remove `position: absolute` from the style and leave it at:

```
div.avatar-block .item-avatar {
    float: left;
}
```

Here's the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9zru/3/) with the result.